# Cannot install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9' on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just started to learn Ruby on Rails by following some tutorials. Rails had been working well until one day it just stopped working. The code following is what I got from the Terminal when I tried to run rails:

```
$ rails -v
Looks like your app's ./bin/rails is a stub that was generated by Bundler.

In Rails 4, your app's bin/ directory contains executables that are versioned
like any other source code, rather than stubs that are generated on demand.

Here's how to upgrade:

 bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
 rake rails:update:bin         # Use the new Rails 4 executables
 git add bin                   # Add bin/ to source control

You may need to remove bin/ from your .gitignore as well.

When you install a gem whose executable you want to use in your app,
generate it and add it to source control:

 bundle binstubs some-gem-name
 git add bin/new-executable

 WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
  i18n (>= 0.6.9, ~> 0.6)
  json (>= 1.7.7, ~> 1.7)
  tzinfo (~> 1.1)
  minitest (~> 5.1)
  thread_safe (~> 0.1)
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
 WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
Could not find sqlite3-1.3.9 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

So I ran bundle install and gem install sqlite3-1.3.9 but neither of them worked. The code following is from the Terminal when I ran gem install sqlite3-1.3.9:

```
$ sudo gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9'
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... no
sqlite3 is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

But when I tried 'port install sqlite3 +universal', 'yum install sqlite-devel' and 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev', the terminal showed:

```
$ apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
-bash: apt-get: command not found
```

Command is not found even for yum and port. Some people said that I should install ruby-dev package and possibly the libsqlite3-dev (Ubuntu) or sqlite-devel (Fedora) package as well, but I don't know how to do it. What should I do? Should I reinstall Ruby and Rails? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: What is the result of running `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9'` (without `sudo`)?

Comment: I think you haven't installed the command line tools, which should include sqlite3. Then `bundle install`.

Comment: @Davidann, the result of running that is                           `$ gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.9'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.` Thank you!